# Why is a 0 being appended to the results of my ajax .load() call from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm using the .load() function in jquery to insert the results of a php file to an element. My code looks likethis:

```
$('#edit .postcontent').load('admin-ajax.php', {'action':'qe-getpost'});
```

Everything works great - the returned value is loaded into .postcontent perfectly.  However, a 0 is appended to the end. Every time.  Even if I return nothing, a lonely 0 shows up inside .postcontent.  Can anyone explain what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the 0, but you have an extra ' after #edit, it should read: $('#edit .postcontent')

Comment: Whoops.  That was leftover from taking some things out to simplify the function for posting here.  I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What content-type is admin-ajax.php returning? When you use Fiddler or some other debugging proxy to examine the actual content of the HTTP response, do you see the 0 there (or any other spurious characters)?

Comment: Heh..  Now I feel a little silly.  I was using wordpress' built in ajax functionality, which enables you to use wordpress functions in your ajax response function - and a quick look at THAT code reveals that after every custom call, die('0') runs.  Thanks for forcing me to look at the obvious..